# how to encrypt the request headers in REST calls without using SSL

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Bearer Token Authentication. when i send in my credentials in the form. I can easily grab my password through Fiddler. I can also see the token along with its claim in fiddler.

I can copy this token and use fiddler to make API calls.

This seems to be a huge loophole in my system. How can i prevent a hacker from not using the token and not seeing the credentials in fiddler.

Is there a way to encrypt the request headers in API calls. Is there a way to encrypt the response headers in API ?

Is it possible to do this without using SSL ?

Please help me understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do without SSL, but you will have to pretty much replicate most of the SSL, that is trust, key exchange, encryption.

Technically can be done using private/public key as well, but this really complicates the issue as well.

so, use SSL

Comment: is there some other approach, where in i don't pass the token in the header nor store in cookies, nor pass through the URL?

Answer (score 0):

RFC 6749:

`The authorization server MUST require the use of TLS as described in Section 1.6 when sending requests using password authentication.`